# cant run Django-Responsive2

Tags: javascript, python, django, web, responsive

after following [django-responsive2 documentation](https://django-responsive2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) ,

my html code is :

```html
 {% if device.is_xsmall or device.is_small %}

            <div class="col-sm">
                <img src="images/myimage_sm.jpg" alt="Descriptive alt tag" />
            </div>

{% elif device.is_medium %}
```

I get this error :

**File "C:\Users\Adminstrator\Desktop\project\project\settings.py", line 147, in 
'verbose_name': *('Small screens'),
NameError: name '*' is not defined**

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you run migrations?

Other than that you would need to provide more code than just an error.

Comment: u gotta try it ur self sir